# The famous blank song

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Note: The first is the same.

```
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  / ⠀    ⠀     ⠀  /  ⠀   ⠀         /      ⠀ ⠀ 
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  / ⠀ ⠀⠀  ⠀  ⠀⠀  /  ⠀   ⠀         / ⠀⠀ ⠀ ⠀     ⠀⠀⠀  ⠀
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  /         ⠀ / ⠀    ⠀          ⠀ ⠀⠀ ⠀ / ⠀   ⠀ ⠀⠀ ⠀ / ⠀⠀ ⠀  ⠀    ⠀   ⠀    ⠀⠀  /  ⠀   ⠀        
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  / ⠀⠀   ⠀  ⠀  ⠀  ⠀  /  ⠀   ⠀         /  ⠀⠀     ⠀  
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  /   ⠀  ⠀   ⠀   / ⠀ ⠀    ⠀    ⠀⠀ ⠀ ⠀⠀⠀  ⠀    ⠀ 
 ⠀  ⠀      ⠀    / ⠀ ⠀     ⠀  ⠀ ⠀  / ⠀⠀   ⠀  ⠀ ⠀⠀ ⠀ ⠀⠀ / ⠀  / ⠀ ⠀⠀    ⠀  ⠀  / ⠀   ⠀ ⠀⠀ ⠀ /   ⠀        ⠀⠀  /  ⠀   ⠀
```

Comment: Too tired to tackle it now but the text is rot13(n zvk bs H+0020 FCNPR, H+200N UNVE FCNPR, naq H+2800 OENVYYR CNGGREA OYNAX)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text is

> made up of three characters: *space*, *hair space* [a thinner space used for typography], and *"braille pattern blank"*.

Treating the

> hair spaces as dots and blank braille patterns as dashes, you get:
>
>  `ARIRE TBAAN TVIR LBH HC / ARIRE TBAAN YRG LBH QBJA / ARIRE TBAAN EHA NEBHAQ NAQ QRFREG LBH / ARIRE TBAAN ZNXR LBH PEL / ARIRE TBAAN FNL TBBQOLR / ARIRE TBAAN GRYY N YVR NAQ UHEG LBH`
>
>  Then, applying rot13 gives:
>  `NEVER GONNA GIVE YOU UP / NEVER GONNA LET YOU DOWN / NEVER GONNA RUN AROUND AND DESERT YOU / NEVER GONNA MAKE YOU CRY / NEVER GONNA SAY GOODBYE / NEVER GONNA TELL A LIE AND HURT YOU`

Comment: ohhh I have mixed feelings about this puzzle