# Will you regret solving this puzzle?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, steganography

It's February and you walk into the Smithsonian American Art Museum. A piece of artwork was recently bought for $2,061,966 USD, but you are confused that the museum bought this ugly artwork that even a 2-year-old could create. When you ask for more info about the painting, they show you a card with `Eicqn : h3HGqtA`. After a while you understand that this is a puzzle and regret seeing it as a puzzle. After you come home you post this on puzzling.stackexchange to see how many people will regret clicking and trying this puzzle.

[image]

Note: To get full credit you must explain what hints/clues there are as well as how to solve it correctly. (Basically use only what is provided in the riddle. Dont guess and check)

Comment: rot13(V pna frr gung vg bayl unf ert, terra naq oyhr (ETO). Qbrf vg unir nalguvat gb qb jvgu urk pbybe pbqrf (abg bayl urk ohg gur pbybe jevggra va nal onfr) be pbybe tnzhg (orpnhfr gur cbfvgvba bs erq, terra naq oyhr cvrprf pna nyvta jvgu gur tnzhg)?)

Comment: Ol hfvat vzntr fgrtnabtencul qrpbqre, V jnf noyr gb rkgenpg nyy gur jbeqf zngpuvat /[n-mN-M0-9]+/ naq gnxvat gur havdhr punenpgref tnir zr gjb fgevatf 1. UVNvnQr06yYuEZzCWLR24 2. VU6YQvN4EXyqPn0L. Qb gurfr unir nal eryngvba gb gur dhrfgvba?

Comment: I assumed the answer will have something to do with rickroll

Comment: @justhalf I feel like everyone is paranoid about getting rickrolled. For example [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116556/dont-decrypt-this-encrypted-string#comment-325967)

Comment: @JohnBrookfields rot13(Qba'g bire ybbx vg. Gur fgrtnabtencul gnt vf gurer sbe n zhpu fvzcyre ernfba. Nsgre lbh fbyir vg lbh jvyy trg vg. Nyfb V pnag tvir njnl gb znal uvagf ohg V jvyy fnl gur chmmyr vf "Frys-pbagnvarq" (Znlor Frys-pbagnvarq vf n uvag?))

Comment: Haha, yeah, since it has been a very popular internet meme, people easily associate the prompt with rickrolling.

Comment: @justhalf Actually I have done that once I did it [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/the-famous-blank-song) and  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: @VarunW. nice one

Comment: rot13(ebg4 sbe Rvpda = vzthe. u3UTdgN unf 7 punef, juvpu vf gur ahzore bs punef sbe n fgnaqneq vzthe yvax. 2,061,966 unf 7 qvtvgf, fb znlor n xrl. 0 zncf gb gur 3, v.r. ab fuvsg. Ohg arvgure s3OSuaH abe w3AUmmT vf n inyvq vzthe vzntr, fb V'z fghzcrq.)

Comment: @LukasRotter Actually I even forgot the answer to the puzzle but I will tell u one thing. rot13 (Ebg vf gur jnl gb tb ohg hfr gur vzntr sbe gur ahzoref. V npghnyyl sbhaq bhg gung gur chmmyr vf synjrq nsgre V choyvfurq vg orpnhfr nqqvat 3 ebg ahzoref jvyy tvir n fgevat gung pna or fbyirq jvgu n qvssrerag ebg.)